# Bokeh column sortable by number

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh

How can I get a `bokeh` table to sort a column by floating point value instead of string value? I have floating point data which the column is continuing to sort as a string so it is not properly sorting in ascending / descending order. Data and code snippet attached.

Data:

```
GB, 15.789, /path/to/A, size, 100.0
GB, 600.123, /path/to/B, size, 100.0
GB, 70.456, /path/to/C, size, 100.0
```

Snippet:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from bokeh.io import output_file, show, save
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.widgets import DataTable, DateFormatter, TableColumn, NumberFormatter

def get_data():
    lines = open('json.tmp', 'r').read().splitlines()

    data = { 
        'unit': [], 
        'value': [], 
        'location': [], 
        'type': [], 
        'tol': [], 
    }   

    for line in lines:
        words = line.split(',')
        data['unit'].append(words[0])
        data['value'].append(words[1])
        data['location'].append(words[2])
        data['type'].append(words[3])
        data['tol'].append(words[4])

    return data

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = get_data()

    output_file("data_table.html")
    source = ColumnDataSource(data)
    columns = [ 
        TableColumn(field="location", title="Path"),
        TableColumn(field="value", title="Value", formatter=NumberFormatter(format="0.0")),
        TableColumn(field="unit", title="Unit", width=10),
        TableColumn(field="type", title="Type", width=20)
    ]   

    data_table = DataTable(source=source, columns=columns)
    save(data_table)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you pass a string to the `ColumnDataSource` instead of a float.
Change the line:

```
data['value'].append(words[1])
```

into:

```
data['value'].append(float(words[1]))
```

[image]